# Decrypting AES from C#, Encrypted from Java

Tags: c#, java, aes, encryption

We are using below code to encrypt in Java

```
public encrypt(String text) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), SALT, ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH); //256 bit
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
    this.ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    this.ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    byte[] bytes = encrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] encrypted = this.ecipher.doFinal(bytes);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

Our vendor is using C# to decrypt the data
His code

```
string Decrypt(string textToDecrypt, string key)
{
    RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
    rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
    byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(textToDecrypt);
    byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
    int len = pwdBytes.Length;
    if (len > keyBytes.Length) {
        len = keyBytes.Length;
    }
    Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
    rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
    byte[] plainText = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText); 
}
```

But he's unable to decrypt the data. He's getting some garbage data.
Any idea how to decrypt using C# for Java Encryption part.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: I am not C# developer. Sorry, but I got to help vendor with fix :(

Comment: Who wrote the C# code then? I barely believe that anybody will be able to shoot this one from the hip...

Comment: As I mentioned, it's vendor party. They were not able to fix up and asking for help as they are unsure of Java. But in the end it's my job to fix their side too. Just a quick question. are they using proper decryption as per my Encryption in java?

Comment: I have no clue... I don't even know what `RijndaelManaged` is... You'll need a debugger to check this out, it won't work this way. And besides, if you know Java, C# won't pose such a challenge at all.

Comment: I think it's a library like BC. or can you post a code which ca decrypt it in C# with default library?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea. This problem is too specific to solve it here, I guess.

Comment: Grab a copy of [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net) or something like it that will let you run C# code and you can debug the C# code.

Comment: @NitinGurram `RijndaelManaged` part of the standard library, it's pretty much `AesManaged` but allows you to change the block size, your vendor should use `AesManaged` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Don't have any allusions of security with your java code. [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) mode not a good choice.

Second, the problem with the C# code is that it's using the raw bytes of the passphase for the key rather than `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1` which the java code is using. The class in C# to do the key generation is [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)

Comment: Quite strongly worded but still made all the necessary points.

Comment: @ChrisCooney I softened it a bit, I guess, when you see the same bad encryption code over and over, there's a strong desire to bludgeon the point across.

Comment: Agreed. It's the same when you see people using MD5 or not using prepared statements in their SQL query. You just have to remember they don't have the same experience you do I guess :)

Comment: Thanks jbtule. But since it's completely internal service [it's not my decision, though I warned them long time back]. And we have lot more security measurements are there. This is just to prevent any db people and normal within organization users not able to see the information.

Comment: Could you please update the C# snippet which i posted with your suggestion. If it was Java, i could have done by hit and trial atleast :)